# how to keep user login in flutter using sharedpreferences

Tags: flutter, navigation

this question have already asked in stack overflow, but I still get problem in my code.. right now, I have Splash Screen, Login and Home Screen... after user login they will navigate to Home Screen, and whenever they close the app before click logout, I want to redirect them to Splash Screen and then Home Screen, is there a way to do that... I have tried using SharedPreferences to save and get a key but before I click logout (just click back button), my app always redirect to my Login screen not my Home screen, is there something that I miss? This is my Main.dart code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my splash screen

```
class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Future check() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String _key = (prefs.getString('key') ?? false);
    if (_key==null) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new LoginScreen()));
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new BottomTab()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      check();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
```

and in my Login screen I have added this code to save my key and then navigate it to Home Screen (BottomTab)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('key', myKey);

Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => BottomTab()));
```

and this is my Home Screen that contains Bottom Tab

```
class _BottomTab extends State<BottomTab> {
Future<bool> _back() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text('exit?'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('ok'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
              ),
FlatButton(
                child: Text('no'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _onTap(int index) {
    setState(() => _myindex = index);
  }

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(), 
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  Widget _myNavigation(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        currentIndex: myindex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <MyTab>[
          MyTab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          MyTab(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider<String>(
      create: (context) async {
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return prefs.getString("username");
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _back,
          child: PageStorage(
            child: pages[_selectedIndex],
            bucket: bucket,
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when you press the back button, the dialog pops up? and then you press and you comes to loginPage?

Comment: No, after I press back button, the dialog pops up an exit the app (I don't click log out) ... And when I open my app again... I want to be redirect directly to splash and then my home screen, but here the problem in my code is...  After I press back button-dialog pops up-my app is exit-and when I open my app.. My app always redirect me to splash screen and then my login screen not home screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have added this code and then your example works fine

```
onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(),
```